# Example for google drive simple upload rest API

Tags: rest, file-upload, google-drive-api, postman, google-apis-explorer

As per the documentation, if I wish to upload only media without any metadata, the simple upload will do. And the documentation says:

[image: Steps to perform simple upload]

So, as per the documentation, I formed the request as follows and the body of the request is binary data:

[image: Simple upload with POSTMAN]

But I am not able to figure out where to set the parent directory information for the media being uploaded if the body is comprised of only media.

Do I need to submit two requests, one for metadata and one for media? For that, we are provided with the `multipart` upload.

Can anyone please help me with a working example of a simple upload?

Comment: Have you tried using the file upload option in the `body` tab? This should be an option in the `form-data` tab.

Comment: @DannyDainton: Yes the body part is holding the binary data of the media. And the video you shared demonstrates the multipart upload but I'm looking for a simple upload where only media is uplaoded

Comment: Would the single request not send with the media type in the body? I maybe confused about what you’re trying to achieve. I’ve seen lots of people mention leaving out the Content-Type header as Postman sets this itself - not sure if that’s the case in this context.

Comment: @DannyDainton: As per the documentation single request will do for a media upload if we don't wish to upload any metadata, I suppose. But there are some links saying that we need to create a metadata in first place and add actual contents in another request. I just want to upload media and that too within a single request, as guided in the documentation

Comment: It’s not an API that I’m familiar with so I’m not sure what the required params that are needed to be a valid request.

Answer (score 1):

The `form-data` section in this Postman  [docs](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/requests) page might help you with entering the file location.

I found a YouTube [video](https://youtu.be/3vqvZmP28KE) on the subject too.